# Device change in pavucontrol not updating Playback stream devices consistently

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm having an issue with pavucontrol (2.0-3). Sometimes when I change the device profile from the Configuration tab, the device isn't automatically updated on the Playback tab for each stream. It usually updates correctly when I first boot and change between devices from the Configuration tab. After a while it stops updating and I have to change the Playback device manually for each stream.

Does anyone know what is causing this or where I should be looking for what could cause this behavior?

Background: My system has several audio devices. I frequently switch between my headphone output and my digital (IEC958) output.

Apologies if I am not using the correct terminology here.